# ios access main window or view

Tags: ios, uiview, window, program-entry-point

I would like to know if there is a simple way to access the main window or view in IOS. Something similar to:

```
[UIScreen mainScreen]
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 50):

Try :

```
UIWindow *frontWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows]
                                                            lastObject];
```

or simply :

```
UIWindow *frontWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
```

Comment: `keyWindow` returned nil for me. `lastObject` returned the correct result. Thx.

Comment: You should use firstObject and not lastObject. See "windows" documentation

Comment: beware `keyWindow`, see my answer below

Answer (score 13):

The main window is best found using `UIWindow * mainWindow = [UIApplication sharedApplication].windows.firstObject;`

Using `keyWindow` can return a keyboard or UIAlertView window, which lie above your application window.

Comment: That's the right answer with explanation! I've broke my head trying to figure out why my view disappearing when there is alertview.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a pointer to some subview in the window, you can easily access its window:

```
UIWindow *window = mySubview.window;
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply clever, works from any class:

```
[(YourAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window];
```

Note: don't forget to import your appDelegate class