# Can I place a UIView the current Navigation Controller?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, xamarin, uinavigationbar, uivisualeffectview

How can I place a UIView overtop of a Navigation Controller?  Is this possible without making my own custom navigation bar and custom tab bar controller out of UIViews?

Let's say I have a UITabBarController and I want to present a blur view overtop of the entire thing.  For the blur view, I'm using the UIVisualEffectView.  But i want the blurview to take up the entire screen including the top navigation bar and the bottom tab bar.  If I push a new view controller, that will take up the entire screen, but then I can't see through it to what's underneath (the tab bar controller's contents).

I could simply hide the navigation bar and tab bar when I animate in the blur view, but that looks awkward because you see the content in the collectionview shift because the navigation bar is hiding... I'd rather not see that shift in the content when the blurview comes up.

[image]

Here's a UITabBarController with stuff in it.

[image]

I want a blur view to cover everything and to be able to see through to the entire UITabBarController and the stuff underneath.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to add the UIView as a subview of the key window. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6820017/ios-access-main-window-or-view) for how to get the key window. However, it's generally best to keep to your own view hierarchy, so...

Another way might be to present a new view controller as a fullscreen modal, and apply the blur/transparency to that modal view.

Comment: But you can't see through that new view controller to the one below it. You can see through while it animates, but as soon as the animation finishes it becomes opaque. I'll probably avoid adding a view to the window. Interesting idea, but is that bad practice?